# Laravel sweetalert deleting id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

how does the error comes up in route is there something went wrong to my code? my route is correct inside script in url, how can i fix?

This is my route web.php

```
Route::post('deletenews/{id}', 'AllSystemController@deletenewsdata')->name('delete.news.data');
```

this is my loop inside my blade

```
 @foreach($news as $row)
 <tr>
<td><img src="{{ asset('storage/news_images')}}/{{$row->display_image}}" class="img-thumbnail" width="50"></td>
<td>{{$row->title}}</td>
<td>{{$row->is_flagship}}</td>
<td>{{$row->category_name}}</td>
<td>{{$row->name}}</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&nbsp;<i class="feather icon-chevron-down"></i></button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/news/view', $row->id)}}" target="_blank">View</a>
    <a style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/news/edit', $row->id)}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
    <a onclick="deleteConfirmation({{$row->id}})" style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" class="dropdown-item">Delete</a>
  </div>
  </div>
 </td>

 </tr>
 @endforeach
```

this is my script inside my blade

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteConfirmation(id) {
    swal({
        title:"Are you sure you want to delete this?",
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
        cancelButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    }).then(function (e) {

        if (e.value === true) {
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{url('/deletestory')}}/" + id,
                data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (results) {
                    if (results.success === true) {
                        swal({
                          title: "Done!",
                          text: results.message,
                          type: "success",
                          showConfirmButton: false
                        });
                        location.reload(true);
                        
                    } else {
                        swal({
                          title: "Error!",
                          text: results.message,
                          type: "error"
                        });
                        location.reload(true);
                        // swal("Error!", results.message, "error");
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            e.dismiss;
        }

    }, function (dismiss) {
        return false;
    })
}
</script>
```

Error: POST http://localhost/kauswagan/deletenews/8 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Did you try out echoing the value from AllSystemController@deletenewsdata function? Also how you are running laravel? using ```php artisan serve``` ?

Comment: I tried to echo data inside AllSystemController@deletenewsdata but keeps this Error: POST http://localhost/kauswagan/deletenews/8 500 (Internal Server Error), im not using php artisan serve i use direct localhost root

Comment: i solve it thank you..